# Error while building v8 in android embedded

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, v8

I tried to import v8 7.6.90 as a static library in my Android NDK project, but it fails at the link process.

Here is my `args.gn` config for v8 build:

```
android_unstripped_runtime_outputs = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
is_debug = false
symbol_level = 1
target_cpu = "arm"
target_os = "android"
use_goma = false
v8_enable_i18n_support = false
v8_static_library = true
is_component_build = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_android_log_stdout = true
```

It did compile and gave me a `libv8_monolith.a` after compiling, I started to set up my Android project then.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(v8 STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties( v8 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libv8_monolith.a)
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

target_include_directories( native-lib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/include)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        v8
        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

build.gradle:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-std=c++0x"
    }
}
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
}
```

native-lib.cpp runs the same example in https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/samples/hello-world.cc

But ld always complains about the error:

```
../../src/compiler/graph-visualizer.cc:0: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
/Users/fredguo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
error: undefined reference to 'v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__ndk1::default_delete<v8::TracingController> >)'
```

I tried to objdump my `libv8_monolith.a`:

`objdump -D app/libs/armeabi-v7a/libv8_monolith.a | grep NewDefault`

```
Disassembly of section .text._ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
_ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
       4:       81 b0 01 2b     blhs    #442884 <_ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE+0x6C210>
Disassembly of section .rel.text._ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
.rel.text._ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
Disassembly of section .ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
.ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
Disassembly of section .rel.ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
.rel.ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE:
Disassembly of section .text._ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
_ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
Disassembly of section .rel.text._ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
.rel.text._ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
Disassembly of section .ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
.ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
Disassembly of section .rel.ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
.rel.ARM.exidx.text._ZN2v811ArrayBuffer9Allocator19NewDefaultAllocatorEv:
```

`_ZN2v88platform18NewDefaultPlatformEiNS0_15IdleTaskSupportENS0_21InProcessStackDumpingENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_17TracingControllerENS3_14default_deleteIS5_EEEE`

should be

`v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__1::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__1::default_delete<v8::TracingController> >)`

However, in the error message, the ld tries to find  `std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::__ndk1::default_delete<v8::TracingController> >)`

I think they have a different namespace, but how do I solve this problem? I found a similar issue here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/Jb1VSouy2Z0, but the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: I believe that adding `use_custom_libcxx=false`to **args.gn**  will solve the problem, see *[How to use linked libraries compiled with libc++ libstdc++ mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734361/192373)*

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue. I tried  use_custom_libcxx=false flag, but this didnt help me. Any solution?
Here is my error log. SampleNDK/app/src/main/cpp/hello-jni.cpp:42: error: undefined reference to 'v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::__ndk1::unique_ptr >)' ../../buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/memory:3586: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_weak()'

Comment: @BABASHANKER I  followed the docs and managed to downgrade to 7.2 and compiles. But I didn't find any luck above 7.2. Here is my `args.gn` in 7.2: ```is_debug = true
target_cpu = "arm"
target_os = "android"
v8_android_log_stdout = false
is_component_build = false
android_unstripped_runtime_outputs = false
v8_enable_backtrace = true
v8_enable_slow_dchecks = true
v8_optimized_debug = false
use_goma = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
``` P.S I don't know how to get a new line in a comment, sorry for the bad format :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modify namespace macro in `v8/buildtools/third_party/libc++/trunk/include/__config`:

from `_LIBCPP_CONCAT(__,_LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION)` to `_LIBCPP_CONCAT(__ndk,_LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the right answer. I had to do this for some v8 7.2+ and v8 8.0 as well.